# python tempfile: how to open several times the temp file?

Tags: python, temporary-files

I am trying to use the tempfile module. (http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/tempfile.html)
I am looking for a temporary file that I could open several times to get several streams to read it.

```
tmp = ...
stream1 = # get a stream for the temp file
stream2 = # get another stream for the temp file
```

I have tried several functions (TemporaryFile, NamedTemporaryFile, SpooledTemporaryFile) and using the fileno method or so but I could not perform what I am looking for.

Any idea of should I just make my own class?

Thanks

### > UPDATE

I get an error trying to open the file with its name...

```
In [2]: t = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
In [3]: t.write('abcdef'*1000000)
In [4]: t.name
Out[4]: 'c:\\users\\mike\\appdata\\local\\temp\\tmpczggbt'
In [5]: f = open(t.name)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IOError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-03b9332531d2> in <module>()
----> 1 f = open(t.name)

IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'c:\\users\\mike\\appdata\\local\\temp\\tmpczggbt'
```

Comment: This sounds like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem); what are you really trying to do here?

Comment: What I want to do is : I fetch an URL and I want to store the data in a temp file if it is too big instead of a string variable. Then I want to read it from several places but did not want to use the same stream. When I use a string, I can create several StringIO from this string without duplicating the data, I was looking for the same behavior to get several streams.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

File objects (be they temporary or otherwise) cannot be read multiple times without re-positioning the file position back to the start.

Your options are:

- To rewind the file object before each read.
- To reopen the file multiple times, creating multiple file objects for the same file.

To rewind, call `.seek(0)` on the file object.

To reopen the file, use a `NamedTemporaryFile` and use a regular `open()` call to re-open the same filename several times. You probably will want to pass `delete=False` to the constructor, especially on Windows, to be able to do this.

Comment: I tried to open it with the name but I have a "Permission denied" error... See the update of my question.

Comment: @YAmikep: Set `delete=False` when creating the `NamedTemporaryFile`.

Comment: Ok that works thanks. I guess now I have to carefully take care of deleting the file by myself. Another thing, I liked the idea of the SpooledTemporaryFile but it does not take the delete arg, I guess I need to handle by myself when I want to keep the data in memory and then use the NamedTemporaryFile when wanted? There is no way to make the SpooledTemporaryFile works the same way to re open several time the file when it has been created.

Comment: You can't do this with a `SpooledTemporaryFile` because it uses a `TemporaryFile()` object internally when rolling over to disk. On Windows that *happens* to be the same class as `NamedTemporaryFile` (it's an alias in fact) but `delete=True` will be set by default and is not overridable.

Comment: You could try to write your own clone from the [python source code](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/tempfile.py) and adjust it to return a `NamedTemporaryFile` with `delete=False` in that case.

Comment: Ok thank you, I looked at the SpooledTemporaryFile class and I think it might be easier to write a simple class to manage a StringIO and a TemporaryFile. I'll switch from the stringIO to the TemporaryFile when needed.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`tempfile.mkstemp()`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.mkstemp). From the documentation:

> Creates a temporary file in the most secure manner possible. There are no race conditions in the file’s creation, assuming that the platform properly implements the os.O_EXCL flag for os.open(). The file is readable and writable only by the creating user ID. If the platform uses permission bits to indicate whether a file is executable, the file is executable by no one. The file descriptor is not inherited by child processes.
>
> Unlike TemporaryFile(), the user of mkstemp() is responsible for deleting the temporary file when done with it.

You can then use the `open()` builtin function to create and open that file several times. Remember to delete the file when you are done, as this is not done automatically.